# How to fix bash: raco: command not found?

Tags: bash, path, racket, environment

```
raco pkg install iracket
-bash: raco: command not found
```

I add path to .bash_profile

```
# Setting PATH for Racket 7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Racket v7.0/bin/raco:$PATH"
```

But it still doesn't work. How can I fix it? Should I add path to .bash_profile or somewhere else? It is macOS.

```
export PATH="/Applications/Racket v7.0/bin:$PATH"
```

This doesn't work also.

Comment: `PATH` should include directories, not individual executable files (which I suspect `/Applications/Racket v7.0/bin/raco` is). Try putting just `/Applications/Racket v7.0/bin` in `PATH` (without `/raco`).

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: 1) Confirm the existence and location of the executable: `ls -l "/Applications/Racket v7.0/bin/raco"`. 2) Confirm that you have reloaded `.bash_profile`: `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Ahhhh, sry, I didn't reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you **source**d the file?

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

It's needed to update your environment variables.

Comment: Yea, that's the problem. Amadan mentioned it in the comment. Is `.bash_profile` doing the same thing?

Comment: Not exactly, because it will only be effective in the parent process' environment (the shell itself), and thus won't be inherited by all child process (e.g. launched instructions).